# Frame.Navigate() vs this.Frame.Navigate()

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

What is the difference between `Frame.Navigate()` and `this.Frame.Navigate()` in a Windows 8.1 Store app?

What difference does this

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Login));
```

have with this?

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Login));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There no difference.

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is
>   also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx